# More efficient way to set textures and colors on svg elements?

Tags: svg, design-patterns

I need to set range of colors on a series of svg elements, using the same semi-transparent png texture on top of each element. There must be a more efficient way to do this...

```
<svg>
    <defs>
        <pattern id="texture1">
            <image xlink:href="texture.png"/>
            <rect fill="red" /> 
        </pattern>

        <pattern id="texture2">
            <image xlink:href="texture.png"/>
            <rect fill="yellow" /> 
        </pattern>

        <pattern id="texture3">
            <image xlink:href="texture.png"/>
            <rect fill="blue" /> 
        </pattern>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

CSS:
.path1 { fill: url(#texture1); } ... etc

This seems super ugly. Suggestions on how to improve it?

Comment: You might have a chance using a filter. What does the texture.png look like?

Comment: I'm also wondering this... I will keep you posted if I find anything.

Comment: Texture.png is a semi-transparent png, but I don't think filters will work for me because of cross-browser compatibility issues. Specifically, IE9 & Android.